# Spanish version of a Francophile

Tags: single-word-requests

I know the word Francophile is someone who likes France and the French. I also know of Anglophiles that is a similar word for the British. Is there such a word for the Spanish though?

Comment: This question made me wonder whether there is a word in English for someone who ardently admires the longtime Spanish dictator Francisco Franco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Iberophile](http://iberophile.blogspot.com/2012/08/iberophilewhats-that.html)* seems to be commonly used to refer to a love of all things Spanish.

[This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=sEyNcwa_3l4C&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=iberophile&source=bl&ots=3Y5VAPnZKF&sig=rCemvNvtcp72DGphwp3RN__Mvzw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBjgKahUKEwiWya_piPjGAhUKlYgKHb4mAQc#v=onepage&q=iberophile&f=false) even uses "Francophile" and "Iberophile" in the same sentence.

Comment: _Iberophile_ is not, in my experience, limited to all things Spanish, but to all thing Iberian. In other words, it includes Catalan, Basque, European Portuguese, etc., but excludes Latin America, Brazilian or Angolan Portuguese, etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet [Common usage](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=iberophile+spanish) would seem to indicate otherwise, not to mention the [etymology of Ibero-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Iberia#Iberia__2) being from the Greek word for "Spaniards."

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can come is "Hispanophile," but this might restrict your love to Spain or it might mean any Spanish-speaking place, of which there are numerous outside the Iberian peninsula.

Comment: This is the option [listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-phil-#National).

Answer (score 1):

Both the Spanish Monarchy and subsequent government of Francisco Franco were generally disliked because of their extreme greed, avarice and authoritarianism. A word for "Love of Spain" therefore never came into common use. Iberophile denotes a love for Iberian culture that includes both Spain and Portugal without any political connotations.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. Please check out the [help topic on how to write a good answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Your answer contains potentially useful information for the original poster, but doesn't cite references that can back up what is in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hispanophile and iberophile are both good, but only hispanophile is on Merriam-Webster