# What is the Japanese equivalent for francophile?

Tags: word-choice

Similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262418/spanish-version-of-a-francophile), what is the term used to refer to people who like Japan or Japanese culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, the equivalent term would be

> Nipponophile

though coloquially or in a more insulting context

> Weeaboo

is sometimes used as well.

Comment: Another word someone might use is Otaku.

Comment: I was going to include that but Otaku is more for people who are into anime, which isn't what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but I feel like it's relevant enough to at least be mentioned.

Comment: I would agree with that. +1 to your comments for additional info. ^_^

Comment: I have never heard either "Nipponophile" or "weeaboo" in my three decades as a Japan resident and Japanophile.

Comment: It may be that the term originated outside of Japan then; I've seen it used in quite a few pages and articles referring to a liking for Japanese/Asian culture.

Answer (score 2):

> Japanophile

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanophile

"Japanophile" is a pretty common expression.